# What to use since Marionette Application Regions are deprecated

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am confused by the Marionette (2.3.0) documentation from the link below that says the Application Regions feature is deprecated. A Layout View should be used instead. Does that mean I should not use `MyApp.addRegions()` any more? Then how should I add my Layout View to my application?

http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.application.html#application-regions

> Application Regions
>
> Warning: deprecated This feature is deprecated. Instead of using the
>   Application as the root of your view tree, you should use a Layout
>   View. To scope your Layout View to the entire document, you could set
>   its el to 'body'. This might look something like the following:
>
> var RootView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({ el: 'body' });

Comment: possible duplicate of [MarionetteJS: Application Regions vs. Layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807663/marionettejs-application-regions-vs-layouts)

Answer (score 4):

I will like to explain with a very simple example the usage of layout view in marionette.

html

```
   <div id="appDiv"></div>

   <script type="text/template" id="mainTemplate">
       <div id="div1"></div>
       <div id="div2"></div>    
   </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="itemTempFirst">
       <p>some text item 1 view</p>
       <p>some text item view 1</p>
    </script>

     <script type="text/template" id="itemTempSecond">
       <p>some text item 2 view</p>
       <p>some text item view 2</p>
     </script>
```

JS Code:--

```
     var app = new Marionette.Application();
     var LayoutViewObj = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
         template:"#mainTemplate",
         el:"#appDiv",
         regions:{
            reg1:"#div1",
            reg2:"#div2"
         }
     });

      var layoutViewInstance = new LayoutViewObj();
      layoutViewInstance.render();

      var ItemView1Obj = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
         template:"#itemTempFirst"
      });

      var ItemView2Obj = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
         template:"#itemTempSecond"
      });

      var item1 = new ItemView1Obj();

      var item2 = new ItemView2Obj();

      layoutViewInstance.getRegion("reg1").show(item1);

      layoutViewInstance.getRegion("reg2").show(item2);
```

Please note I was trying without el element earlier , but i got no luck and as I used el:"#someElem" life got easier